# Select all in ListBox by clicking a Button

Tags: c#

I would like to highlight all content of a ListBox by a press of a button, but it doesn't work.

```
  private void selectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       resultbox.Select();
  }
```

I also wanted to have a "label" to count how many rows has the same ListBox.
What should I do?

Comment: What is `RESULTBOX`?

Comment: _What should I do?_
Giving more information. What is resultbox? A `TextBox`? A `TextBlock`? What UI language you are using?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom ListBox, sorry.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on button click:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myListBox.Items.Count;i++)
 {
      myListBox.SetSelected(i, true);
 }
```

Comment: Agreed, making sure that `myListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;` or `myListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;`

Comment: And the second question:
I also wanted to have a "label" to count how many rows has the same ListBox. What should I do?

Comment: myListBox.Items.Count returns int value with the rows count.